# I am trying to add a custom scrollbar component to my list of options inside MUI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to add this scroll- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scrollbars-2
to the [Material UI autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#asynchronous-requests) list of options.
My application is using the same scroll component everywhere and the UI looks really off with the traditional default scroll that we have on mui autocomplete.

Link to component-
https://codesandbox.io/s/eioiuz?file=/demo.tsx

Here's how it looks right now- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwvif.png

Here's how I want the scrollbar to look like- https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM367.png

Comment: Please copy and paste code here instead of giving a link. This is because code on other sites can change over time. See this [FAQ for more detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/17493431)

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to solve this problem is by styling the default  tag used by MUI Autocomplete list component box. For Example `ul::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 4px; }` will reduce the size of the scrollbar.